# Java Tensorflow inference issues with a frozen CNN model

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am encountering some issues regarding the use of the Java Tensorflow API.

Basically, I am trying to predict some images using a frozen model that I trained in Python, but I want to do these inferences with Tensorflow in Java for some applications that I will develop later, should this work.

I started by exporting my Python model as a .pb file which can then be loaded in Tensorflow and it can be used for inference purposes, which I tested in Python and it works without any problem.

Then, I tried to modify the LabelImage.java example provided in the Java Tensorflow examples that can be found on GitHub (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java). I basically modified the paths of the model and the image that I would use. And after successfully correcting some errors, the code was runnable, but I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Generic conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
 [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_1_0_0, conv2d_1/kernel)]]
```

I am quite new in Java and Tensorflow in general and I tried to find similar errors such as the one I got and I did not find anything useful. I wonder if the error is trying to tell me that the current Tensorflow API for Java does not support convolutions, which I would be quite surprised if it was the case. Anyway, I am a bit lost about what I could do to solve this issue and I hope that someone can help  me figure out a fix.

**Some details**: I builded and trained a U-Net model on Keras and used a method from some user on GitHub that converts a trained Keras model into a .pb file which can be reloaded on Tensorflow and runned for inference (user: https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow). This reloading and inference part works perfectly in Python (I tested it to be sure).

The error seems to be happening in this code chunk:

```
 private static float[] executeInceptionGraph(byte[] graphDef, Tensor<Float> image) {
try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
  g.importGraphDef(graphDef);
  try (Session s = new Session(g);
      // Generally, there may be multiple output tensors, all of them must be closed to prevent resource leaks.
      Tensor<Float> result =
          s.runner().feed("input_1", image).fetch("conv2d_24/Sigmoid").run().get(0).expect(Float.class)) {
    final long[] rshape = result.shape();
    if (result.numDimensions() != 2 || rshape[0] != 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          String.format(
              "Expected model to produce a [1 N] shaped tensor where N is the number of labels, instead it produced one with shape %s",
              Arrays.toString(rshape)));
    }
    int nlabels = (int) rshape[1];
    return result.copyTo(new float[1][nlabels])[0];
  }
}
```

This code was not changed, as I said I just changed the input paths that would point to my model and a sample image for testing. The exact parts that I changed can be found below:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println("TensorFlow version: " + TensorFlow.version());

byte[] graphDef = readAllBytesOrExit(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\joao_\\Documents\\GitHub\\Tensorflow-to-PB\\java_code\\src\\main\\resources\\test.pb"));
byte[] imageBytes = readAllBytesOrExit(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\joao_\\Documents\\GitHub\\Tensorflow-to-PB\\java_code\\src\\main\\resources\\02.png"));

try (Tensor<Float> image = constructAndExecuteGraphToNormalizeImage(imageBytes)) {
  float[] labelProbabilities = executeInceptionGraph(graphDef, image);
  int bestLabelIdx = maxIndex(labelProbabilities);
}
```

I hope these informations can be enough for understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I found out the answer to my own question.

Basically, the error is related to the fact that I was feeding an image to the model which did not have an appropriate size (my image was 512x512 and my model only takes 256x256 images). So, I guess the problem was the input tensor not having the right dimensions.

Hope this post can still be useful by helping people with the same issue.